# Java FlowLayout does paint my pictures tiny

Tags: java, image, awt, flowlayout

My FlowLayout does paint the pictures very small so i nearly cant see them.

Whats my mistake ?

My plan later is, that it will look like this:

[image]

So now iam working on the inner Flow Layout which displays one line of colorSeperations or histograms.

```
    public Window(String pfad, Image bild) {
         this.pfad = pfad;
         this.bild = bild;

         int[] actualScalation1 = new int[2];
         Scaler scalerImg1 = new Scaler(bild);
         actualScalation1 = scalerImg1.getActualScalation();

         // int RGB-int Array
         int [][] rgbColorsForPicture;

         // Gib mir das Bild als BufferedImage
         BufferedImage pictureForColorSeperation = null;
        try {
            pictureForColorSeperation = BufferImage.drawthePicture(pfad);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         // Gib mir das Bild als RGB-int Array
         rgbColorsForPicture = ImageToolK.readRGBvalues(pictureForColorSeperation);
         // Erstelle den roten Farbauszug
         ColorSeperation farbauszugRot = new ColorSeperation(rgbColorsForPicture, 0, 0, 0, actualScalation1[0], actualScalation1[1], 0.5);
         farbauszugRot.createColorSeperation();

         ColorSeperation farbauszugGruen = new ColorSeperation(rgbColorsForPicture, 0, 0, 1, actualScalation1[0], actualScalation1[1], 0.5);
         farbauszugGruen.createColorSeperation();

         ColorSeperation farbauszugBlau = new ColorSeperation(rgbColorsForPicture, 0, 0, 2, actualScalation1[0], actualScalation1[1], 0.5);
         farbauszugBlau.createColorSeperation();

         Histogram histogramRot = new Histogram(rgbColorsForPicture, 0, 0, 0, bild.getHeight(null), bild.getWidth(null), 1, 1);
         histogramRot.createHistogram(bild.getHeight(null), bild.getWidth(null));

         PicturePanel panelbild1 = new PicturePanel(bild, actualScalation1[0], actualScalation1[1]);
         PicturePanel panelbild2 = new PicturePanel(bild, actualScalation1[0], actualScalation1[1]);
         PicturePanel panelbild3 = new PicturePanel(bild, actualScalation1[0], actualScalation1[1]);


         /**
          * 
          * LAYOUTEN
          */

         Panel panel1 = new Panel();
         Panel glDiagramsAndSeperations = new Panel();

         panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));
//       ((FlowLayout) panel1.getLayout()).setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
//       GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
         GridLayout mainWindow = new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0);
         glDiagramsAndSeperations.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
//
//       GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
         setLayout(mainWindow);  // GridBagLayout setzen

//       glDiagramsAndSeperations.add(panel1);
//       
         panel1.add(farbauszugRot);
         panel1.add(farbauszugGruen);
         panel1.add(farbauszugBlau);


//
//       panel1.add(panelbild1); 
//       panel1.add(panelbild2);

         add(panel1);


         this.setBackground(new Color(232, 232, 232)); 

         pack();
         setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Try printing out the `getPreferredSize()` of each of the `ColorSeperation `s and of `panel1`. Maybe they just want to be small.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Expanding on Russell's suggestion, did you override the getPreferredSize() method of your custom panel to return the size of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `Image` as [Icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) then `Image` should be resiziable up to maximum `Icon's` `getWidht` and `getHeight`

since your topic is about `FlowLayout`, code snipped that you posted here showed usage of `GridLayout`, that could be correct `LayoutManager` if you accepting that all `Object` in the `Grid` will have the same `Bounds` on the screen

Comment: I cant, i have to use only AWT, not SWING. No other chance?

Comment: please don't take as attack to your person, why do you use API that came from last milenium, from year 2002 is there Swing, you must have got important reason for use AWT instead of Swing, e.g. implementations for OpenGL

Comment: yes but its the task and i designed the program (paint methods in panels) for that, i dont want/can change to swing now in this project. SO, is there a way to do this with AWT?

Comment: there are three areas used 1) paint() method --> replace any number for Widht and Height with getWidht/getHeight then your BufferedImage should be resizible/cropped scallable by rules that came from used LayoutManager 2) this change from paint() to the Icon is question pass BufferedImage to the Icon, then Icon to the JLabel 3) as mentioned post a SSCCE, because your code snipped doesn't showed whatever about paint and sizing ....

Comment: Why can't you change to Swing?  Basically all you have to do is add a "J" to all your components.